# How to enable read receipts for messages in iMessage on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, messages

I can't find any way to enable read receipts for messages on Mountain Lion.

Read receipts are the iOS term for acknowledgements that show wether or not a message has been read yet or not.

Does Messages for Mountain Lion support read receipts at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Messages app section of the Apple Mountain Lion ["what's new" page](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/):

> Turn on read receipts, and they’ll see when you’ve read a message.

According to this [OS X Daily post](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/29/enable-or-disable-read-receipts-in-imessage-for-mac/), you can send read receipts in the Message app by following these steps:

> 1. Open Preferences in iMessage, and select the “Accounts” tab
> 2. Select
>      the Message account from the left
> 3. Check the box next to “Send Read
>          Receipts” to enable
> 4. Close out of iMessage Preferences

Screenshot from this post:
[image]

I can confirm the presence of the checkbox on my own Mac.

Comment: Thanks! What an awkward place =/ too bad googling this gave me 10 pages of Mountain Lion reviews talking about the same generic set of new apps lol -.-'